# Granting a permission of a stored procedure to a user

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to allow a stored procedure for a user, but struggling to get it right. Hopefully I'm on the right track, thanks for the help.

```
GO 
Alter role ReportDeveloper
Add sp_GetActiveProductInfo   
GRANT EXECUTE ON ReportDeveloper TO employee_usr;
```

Comment: You need just the last line

Comment: Just want toa add that you should not use `sp_` as the stored procedure name prefix since that designates system stored procedures: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It rather should be like below per [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/grant-permissions-on-a-stored-procedure#a-nametsqlprocedurea-using-transact-sql)

```
USE DB_NAME;   
GRANT EXECUTE ON OBJECT::sp_GetActiveProductInfo
    TO employee_usr;  
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Grant permission to database role not user.

```
USE DB_NAME;   
GRANT EXECUTE ON sp_GetActiveProductInfo TO ReportDeveloper;  
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as ;

```
USE databse;   
GRANT EXECUTE ON sp_GetActiveProductInfo TO employee_usr;  
GO
```

If you add this user to a `Role` you will `Grant` the permission to the `Role` where your user is member in :

```
USE databse;   
GRANT EXECUTE ON sp_GetActiveProductInfo TO ReportDeveloper;  
GO
```